# do something when counter = x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, if-statement, counter

I have a counter that make `counter++` every time one image touches another image.

Now what I want to do is: `if counter=2; do something`, but I always get an error:

> Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Here is a part of the code:

```
-(void)checkcollision {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(flakeImage.frame, viewToRotate.frame)) {
       counter++;
    }
}

-(void)checknumber {
    if(counter=2) {
        viewToRotate.alpha=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, counter is also declared incorrectly. Make it an int rather than a pointer.

Comment: where do I have to put the int counter; please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you perhaps doing this:

```
if (counter = 2) {
    // Do something.
}
```

This is a common error in `if` statements. The correction would be:

```
if (counter == 2) {    // Note the "==", instead of "="
    // Do something.
}
```

This is just a guess though - I would need to see some more information about the error, or about what you want to do.

**EDIT**

Ah - have seen your newly posted code, confirming what I stated above. Your code reads that you are trying to assign the value '2' to `counter` in the `if` statement. You want the `==` to make this a check for equality.

Comment: This guy's crystal ball is on FIRE! good answer on a bad question.

Comment: yes but when i do this xcode tell me for the same line :comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: This is why you write conditionals backwards. if (2 == counter); the compiler will catch your mistake if you omit one of the equals signs.

Comment: @Arvin: The pointer/integer comparison error means that you have defined your `counter` as some kind of `id` type. Find the line that you initialise the counter, and make sure you're not using a `*` with the variable name. It should be something like: `NSInteger counter;`, **NOT**: `NSInteger *counter;`. I don't know what type your `counter` variable is exactly, but if it's anything like an `int` or `NSInteger`, you need to know that these are not pointers to objects.